# Iterating through ECL Mount Points

Tags: ecl

I have an integration which adds ECL items to workflow when the external system changes the asset. This is working quite well for a hard coded mount point for a specific publication. I would now like to remove my hard coded values, and make the code work for all mount points which implement my specific ECL provider.

Is there a way to iterate though all of the ECL Mount Points configured for my CM using the Core Service (or other API)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available through the ECL session.

```
IEclSession.GetContentLibraryUris(int publicationId)
```

As indicated requires a publication as input, so depending on your needs you might need to loop over the publications and call this method for each publication. You can cache the result if you need to perform this operation often.

The URIs return can then be passed to

```
IEclSession.GetContentLibrary(IEclUri eclUri)
```

which will instantiate the Context of your provider and return it.

Comment: Thanks Lars - That gets me pretty close. However my Mount Points could be BluePrinted, so when I iterate through all my pubs and call GetContentLibraryUris(), I get copies of the inherited MountPoints. I can't seem to find out a way to check if the MountPoint is inherited or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Get the BluePrint for the publications through CM. Once you have the BluePrint and the list of mountpoint URIs for each publication it should just be a matter of checking the publication parents to see if the mountpoint is also available there - if it is, the mount point is shared.
Be careful though, it only works if the user has access to the mountpoint in all relevant publications.

Comment: I guess I can do that - it would have been nice to be able to just get a list of the configured mount points some how.